# Format of current time returned by python changed

Tags: python, datetime, time, format

I have been using the following code to retrieve the current time:
`str(datetime.datetime.now())`

It used to return a string like this:

> '2022-07-08 10:09:01.231474'

Recently, it started adding plus zero zero (+00) to the timestamp, like this:

> '2022-07-08 10:09:01.231474+00'

We use docker and the image is rebuilt automatically, so I'm thinking that maybe the operative system settings were updated. Has anyone seen such a change, ever?

Comment: I'm running Python 3.9.9 and I got `2022-07-14 15:52:36.929797` (no +00)

Comment: Sometimes functions are implemented by the underlying C equivalent function so it could easily be affected by an OS setting.

Comment: that would maybe go back to the `__str__` [method](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6cbb57f62d345d7a5d6aeb1b3b5d37a845344d5e/Lib/datetime.py#L2051) to be changed, or some method down the chain, e.g. [isoformat](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6cbb57f62d345d7a5d6aeb1b3b5d37a845344d5e/Lib/datetime.py#L2005) and so on. Can you tell if `datetime.datetime.now()` has the tzinfo defined? Although, if so, I'd still have no clue why that would happen nor why it would show only the hours (instead of normal +-hh:mm).